# Open Source PDF editor to make files non-printable

Tags: pdf

I need an open source solution to simply make any PDF unprintable.  I know there's questions about editors, but I need this particular feature only and editing the content isn't a concern.

Comment: How do you stop someone from taking a screenshot and printing that?

Comment: Be aware that setting permissions on PDF documents like that is only kid-sister grade protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it quickly with pdftk: http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/

Use something like:

> pdftk my.pdf output noprinting.pdf owner_pw *MYSTRONGPASSWORD* allow

The `allow` parameter has no argument (defaults to `none`). It seems, that you have to set some owner password (otherwise, printing won't be really disabled).

See the documentation in my link for more options!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `qpdf` command tool.

```
qpdf input.pdf --encrypt "" "MY_PASSWORD" 256 --print=none -- output.pdf
```

- For technical discussion of how PDF encryption works, see [PDF Encryption](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/encryption.html#pdf-encryption).
- To learn more about how to create encrypted files with `qpdf`, see [QPDF Encryption](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#encryption).